# download and resize an external image

Tags: php, image-processing

How do you download, resize and store an image from a remote server using php? 
This is the code I am using

```
$temp_image = file_get_contents($url);
$image = imagecreatefromstring($temp_image);
$thumb = imageToCanvas($image,100,75,true);
imagejpeg($thumb,$base_image_path . $thumb_path,90)


function imageToCanvas($_image, $_canvasWidth, $_canvasHeight, $forceScale=false,$x=false,$y=false) 
{
    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($_canvasWidth, $_canvasHeight);
    $imageinfo = getimagesize($_image);
    $sourceWidth = $imageinfo[0];
    $sourceHeight = $imageinfo[1];  
    $sourceImage = openImage($_image);
    imagecopyresampled($newImage, $sourceImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $_canvasWidth, $_canvasHeight, $sourceWidth, $sourceHeight);
    return $newImage;
}

function openImage($file) 
{
 // *** Get extension
 $extension = strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));
 switch($extension) {
   case '.jpg': case '.jpeg':
     $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
     break;
   case '.gif':
    $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
     break;
   case '.png':
     $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
     break;
   default:
     $img = false;
     break;
 }
 return $img; 
}
```

Doesn't work and I don't know why.

`$sourceWidth` & `$sourceHeight` doesn't have a value so I presume `$image` is in the wrong format

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function in php called `openImage` so that would be a problem if you don't define it yourself.

If you do have it defined, what does it look like and are you receiving any errors?

**Edit:** Based on your comments the problem would seem to be that you treat the input parameter of your `openImage` function as a file path. However, when you call it you are feeding it an image resource, the result of `imagecreatefromstring`.

Comment: function openImage($file)
{
// *** Get extension
$extension = strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));

   switch($extension)
   {
        case '.jpg':
        case '.jpeg':
            $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            break;
        case '.gif':
            $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
            break;
        case '.png':
            $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
            break;
        default:
            $img = false;
            break;
 }
 return $img;
}

Comment: This is it - function openImage($file)
{
// *** Get extension
$extension = strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));

   switch($extension)
   {
        case '.jpg':
        case '.jpeg':
            $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            break;
        case '.gif':
            $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
            break;
        case '.png':
            $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
            break;
        default:
            $img = false;
            break;
 }
 return $img;
}

Comment: @P Whittaker If this answer solved your problem, just mark it as accepted. You need a bit more rep to be able to comment on other peoples posts.

Comment: I know I should but I couldn't see anything  that said accepted. Where abouts am I suppose to click?

Comment: @P Whittaker It's the check-mark below the vote-count on the top-left of the answer :-)

Comment: Ah sorry you mean the tick. I didn't spot that. Ok It is now ticked

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a linux server and ghostscript is installed - here is an easier way

```
shell_exec("convert in.jpg -resize 100x75 out.jpg")
```